# Anyone know why this loop gives 2x my intended result?

Tags: javascript

This is a problem I have for `totalMade` variable and the `totalEntry` variable. The final tally of the variables always doubles (it's always two times the number it's supposed to be). I snooped around and found out that the tally is normal after the first if statement, then it suddenly doubles after finishing the entire for-in loop. Any ideas what the problem might be?

`db` is an array that contains an object in every cell. There are hundreds of cells/hundreds of objects.

Here's the code for reference:

```
for (var z in db) {
    if (isNaN(Number(db[z]["Balance ($)"])) && isNaN(Number(db[z]["Made ($)"]))) {
    } else {
        if (db[z].Opponent === "Cancelled") {
        } else {
            totalEntry += Number(db[z]["Entry ($)"]);
            totalMade += Number(db[z]["Made ($)"]);
            cleanArray.push(db[z]);
            dateLists.push(db[z].Date);
            sampleData.push(Number(db[z].Score));

            if (db[z].Type === "alpha") {
                totalAlphaEntries++;
            } else if (db[z].Type === "beta") {
                totalBetaEntries++;
            } else if (db[z].Type === "gamma") {
                totalGammaEnties++;
            } else if (db[z].Type === "theta") {
                totalThetaEntries++;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the `totalMade` variable global and this code being called in an event handler?  If you don't reset the totals each time, you might just be running this code more often that expected.

Comment: How many times does it run the for loop? You say it's correct after the first iteration. How about the second, the n'th?

Comment: db is an array or an object?

Comment: be warned that javascript's for construct may not be doing what you expect:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/500531/4206756

Comment: do: console.log(db[z]) and see logs in browser and then do checking manually. I think data that comes and what You think that would be are not same. check this also: console.log(Number(db[z]["Entry ($)"]));

Comment: db is an array of hundreds of objects.

Comment: if its an array use `db.forEach()` or the traditional `for(var i = 0; i < db.lengthl i++)`. `for in` is meant for iterating object properties.

Comment: it is an array, but in each cell, there is an object that is iterated through to get the specific data that I need.

Comment: You're not iterating the object, you're retrieving property values.  You should, however, iterate the array properly, as mentioned.

Comment: alright, thanks for the suggestions. I'll re-write the logic and use your suggestions.